# Difference between doseq and for in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What's the difference between doseq and for in Clojure?  What are some examples of when you would choose to use one over the other?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The difference is that `for` builds a lazy sequence and returns it while `doseq` is for executing side-effects and returns nil.

```
user=> (for [x [1 2 3]] (+ x 5))
(6 7 8)
user=> (doseq [x [1 2 3]] (+ x 5))
nil
user=> (doseq [x [1 2 3]] (println x))
1
2
3
nil
```

If you want to build a new sequence based on other sequences, use for. If you want to do side-effects (printing, writing to a database, launching a nuclear warhead, etc) based on elements from some sequences, use doseq.

Comment: now that are much side-effects ...  launching a nuclear warhead :)

Comment: Thanks! I had pulling my (long gone) hair with "for" that it never fire my nuclear warheads over my list of items. "doseq" sure did.

Answer (score 70):

Note also that `doseq` is eager while `for` is lazy. The example missing in Rayne's answer is

```
(for [x [1 2 3]] (println x))
```

At the REPL, this will generally do what you want, but that's basically a coincidence: the REPL forces the lazy sequence produced by `for`, causing the printlns to happen. In a non-interactive environment, nothing will ever be printed. You can see this in action by comparing the results of

```
user> (def lazy (for [x [1 2 3]] (println 'lazy x)))
#'user/lazy

user> (def eager (doseq [x [1 2 3]] (println 'eager x)))
eager 1
eager 2
eager 3
#'user/eager
```

Because the `def` form returns the new var created, and not the value which is bound to it, there's nothing for the REPL to print, and `lazy` will refer to an unrealized lazy-seq: none of its elements have been computed at all. `eager` will refer to `nil`, and all of its printing will have been done.

Comment: How does doseq handle evaluation of infinite lazy sequence? bad idea? only call it on finite sequences, either eager or lazy?

Comment: @johnbakers It will block forever until the evaluation is interrupted. Clojure never attempts to handle infinite sequences in a different way than finite sequences.

Comment: Printing the symbol 'lazy, which is the same name as the def, is really confusing. Use the string "lazy".