# Clojure: buffered reader in for loop

Tags: clojure

I have a large text file I want to process in Clojure.
I need to process it 2 lines at a time.

I settled on using a for loop so I could pull 2 lines for each pass with the following binding (rdr is my reader):

```
[[line-a line-b] (partition 2 (line-seq rdr))]
```

(I would be interested in knowing other ways to get 2 lines for each loop iteration but that is not the point of my question).

When trying to get the loop to work (using a simpler binding for these tests), I am seeing the following behavior that I can't explain:

Why does

```
(with-open [rdr (reader "path/to/file")]  
    (for [line (line-seq rdr)]  
          line))
```

trigger a Stream closed exception

while

```
(with-open [rdr (reader "path/to/file")]  
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]  
        (println line)))
```

works?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725417/difference-between-doseq-and-for-in-clojure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for is lazy and just returns the head of the sequence that will eventually read the data from the file. **The file is already closed when the for's contents are printed** by your repl. you can fix this pu wrapping the `for` in a `doall`

```
(with-open [rdr (reader "path/to/file")]  
    (doall (for [line (line-seq rdr)]  
      line)))
```

Though this unlazys the sequence.

here is a sample of a function out of my misc.clj that lazily closes the file at it's end:

```
(defn byte-seq [rdr]
  "create a lazy seq of bytes in a file and close the file at the end"
  (let [result (. rdr read)]
    (if (= result -1)
     (do (. rdr close) nil)
     (lazy-seq (cons result (byte-seq rdr))))))
```

Comment: ``(byte-seq)`` looks nice - Have you considered exceptions from ``(.rdr read)`` ? could you get, say, an encoding exception and leak the open stream?

Comment: yes, that's completely correct. It also leaks the handle if you don't read the whole sequence.