# Why does Clojure's for macro only accept one body expression?

Tags: clojure

Clojure's `for` macro accepts two arguments: a sequence of binding forms, and a body expression.  As such, if I want to do multiple things in the loop, I have to wrap multiple expressions in a `do` block to make them a single expression.

Compare:

```
(doseq [a (range 3)]
  (prn 'a a)
  (inc a))
```

to:

```
(for [a (range 3)]
  (prn 'a a)
  (inc a))
```

The `doseq` works as expected.  The `for` complains:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (3) passed to: core/for
```

My question is, why doesn't this work?  Why didn't the designer(s) of Clojure allow multiple "body" expressions in the for loop, like they did in `doseq` and `when`?  It's not as if there is any semantic ambiguity, right?

Comment: One big difference is that `for` is lazy, while `doseq` (being primarily for inducing side-effects) is not.  `when` evaluates its body in an implicit `do`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4725417

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clojure's `for` is not a loop, it is lazy list comprehension. Since only the value of last expression in the body of a (implicit) `do` is returned, any other expressions would have to exist merely for side effects. Execution for side-effects is the job of `doseq`, which is why it has an implicit `do`. That `for` does not should be a reminder, do you really want side effects in your lazy sequence? Though there are legitimate reasons for doing so, care is warranted that those side effects execute when you want.

```
(def foo (for [a (range 32)]
           (do
             (prn (str "a is " a))
             (inc a))))

(take 1 foo)
;=>
  ("a is 0"
   "a is 1"
   ...
  "a is 31"
  1) ; <= the return value

(take 10 foo)
;=>
  (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) ; aw, no side effects this time
```

Comment: A good answer, although I think that the chunking part at the end is mostly a red herring, and not explained well enough to be useful anyway.