# Are there any differences between doseq and for combined with dorun?

Tags: clojure

I am well-aware of [the difference between `doseq` and `for`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4725417/465378), but the two seem extremely similar. In fact, it seems to me like `doseq` could easily be implemented as a macro in terms of `for`.

```
(defmacro doseq' [bindings & body]
  `(dorun (for ~bindings ~@body)))
```

Are there any functional differences between this implementation and Clojure's implementation of `doseq`, or are they effectively the same (modulo some possible performance differences)?

Answer (score 2):

from a practical perspective the fact that `for` returns a lazy sequence means that it won't work in core.async where doseq does because it runs entirely within the same function.

```
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :refer [chan go <! <!! >!]])
```

using doseq:

```
user> (let [stuff (chan)]
        (go (while true
              (println (<! stuff))))
        (go (doseq [a (range 4)]
              (>! stuff a))))
#object[clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel 0x523a18bc "clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@523a18bc"]
user> 0
1
2
3
```

using for and dorun:

```
user> (let [stuff (chan)]
        (go (while true
              (println (<! stuff))))
        (go (dorun (for [a (range 4)]
                     (>! stuff a)))))
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod '-item-to-ssa' for dispatch value: :fn, compiling:(form-init5662188991458325584.clj:4:9)
```

fails because it tries to cross a function call within a go block and hence escapes from the go macro's scope.