# Printing out a matrix in Clojure

Tags: matrix, clojure

I have to print out a given matrix in clojure. The goal is to output the matrix in the IO but only have nil as return value.

Here is an example:

```
(def em [[1 0 0] [0 1 0] [0 0 1]])

(print-matrix em)
=> 1 0 0
   0 1 0
   0 0 1
nil
```

In the example above the output should be the matrix and `nil` should be the return value of the function `print-matrix`.
For now I have implemented the function `print-matrix` as following:

```
(defn print-matrix [coll]
  (for [row coll]
    (println
     (apply str
            (interpose " " row)))))
```

Nevertheless I do not have any output but the following as return value:

```
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
(nil nil nil)
```

In my opinion I am doing something wrong with differentiate how to output or return values.
Can anyone help me to clearify this task for me? :)

Comment: just to mention it (it will not solve the immediate problem): there are pretty printers for your REPL - they will help making outputs like this more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println` always returns `nil`.  You can get what you want by using `with-out-str` as follows:

```
  (let [ret-val-1 (println "hello") ; (1)
        ret-val-2 (with-out-str
                    (println "hello"))] ; (2) 
    (println :ret-val-1 ret-val-1)
    (println :ret-val-2 ret-val-2))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
hello                  ; printed by (1)
:ret-val-1 nil         
:ret-val-2 hello
```

Note that there is no output to the terminal from (2) since it has been captured by `with-out-str`.

I do this so often that I [have a pre-built function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.197/api/tupelo.core#pretty-str) `pretty-str` for this purpose:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [clojure.string :as str]))

(def data
  {:a "some really big & long string that takes up space over & over "
   :b {:c (vec (range 23))
       :e (thru 1 10)}})

(def matrix
  (forv [ii (range 8)]
    (forv [jj (range 12)]
      (mod (+ ii jj) 10))))

(dotest
  (println :out-1) (println (pretty-str data))
  (println :matrix) (println (pretty-str matrix)))
```

with output:

```
:out-1
{:a "some really big & long string that takes up space over & over ",
 :b
 {:c [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22],
  :e [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]}}

:matrix
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2]
 [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3]
 [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4]
 [4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
 [7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]]
```

Even easier to use is the [spyx-pretty](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.197/api/tupelo.core#spyx-pretty) function:

```
(spyx-pretty matrix)
```

which prints:

```
matrix => 
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2]
 [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3]
 [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4]
 [4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
 [7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]]
```

The `x` in `spyx` stands for "explicit", so it automatically prints the expression it is given.  Full docs [are here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer to the topic! It state out very clearly what my understanding problem was with println and the value its returning. Nevertheless for my exact problem doseq is doing the trick, because I want to deal with the output as a side-effect. In this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725417/difference-between-doseq-and-for-in-clojure is the solution for me, I just don’t know where to search after initially.